# can't manage dictionary in a function on Fabric.api

Tags: python, function, dictionary, fabric

I'm using fabric for the first time to manage some automation around systemimager.
The concept is simple: i want to send a systemimager command to X hosts.

```
host_dict = {
'192.168.1.1': 'hostname1',
'192.168.1.2': 'hostname2',
'192.168.1.3': 'hostname3',
}   #list of servers to backup

env.hosts = host_dict.keys() #we initialize the env host for fabric

def prepare_client():
   # A function to send prepare_client command to a remoteserver by his hostname
   print("Executing prepare_client on %s" % (env.host))
   run("si_prepareclient --server " + env.host + " --yes")
   time.sleep(30) #30 sec to let prepare_client to complete
```

I would like to use the keys of my host_dict in my functions.
Like this:

```
def prepare_client():
# A function to send prepare_client command to a remoteserver by his 
hostname
    print("Executing prepare_client on %s" % (host_dict(env.host)))
```

But i receive this error:

> ## fab prepare_client
>
> ```
> print("Executing prepare_client on %s" % (host_dict(env.host))) TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
> ```

Could someone correct me ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: `host_dict[env.host]`, square braces

Comment: what a shame ! Thank you Moses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad,
I did a beginner mistake on calling a dictionary'key.

The syntax is:
host_dict[env.host]

Accordly to https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Thank you Moses Koledoye !